# Making grid files (minimum curvature) from point data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, rasterization, curvature

Is there any way to make a grid file from point data (shape file) in QGIS?

I mean by grid a colored raster file like Geosoft .grd or ERMAPPER .ers file or like.

Minimum curvature would be especially nice to have a gridding algorithm.

Comment: Use Raster - Alalysis -Grid. Documentation of the GDAL program used in the background is in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html.

Comment: Thank you. I have my QGIS on different language and did not understand the word that was used for 'grid' in it.